# How to apply permissions on perform_create in ViewSet DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

This is my View Set:

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyClass.objects.all()

   def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.serializer_class 

        return serializers.MyUserSerializer   

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        employee = models.Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        serializer.save(employee=employee)
```

I want to apply permission before perform_create, this perform_create() should only be called if a currently logged in user is  not a super user. If a currently logged in user is a superuser, default perform_create function should be called.

Edit:
Basically I want to implement the following logic, but with the help of permissions.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            serializer.save()
        else:
            employee = models.Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            serializer.save(employee=employee)
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
  self.request.data.get("title", None)  # read data from request
  if self.request.user.is_authenticated and not self.request.user.is_superuser:
      instance = serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
  else:
      instance = serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use permission_classes in your Viewset class

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyClass.objects.all()

    ...
```

Comment: This will apply IsAuthenticated permission in the whole viewset. I have edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyClass.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.serializer_class 

        return serializers.MyUserSerializer   

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        employee = models.Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        serializer.save(employee=employee)

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        return super().has_permission(request, view)
```

`perform_create` method will be called only then if the user is not a superuser and have permissions.
`has_permission` method will returns **True** for superusers.

Comment: I tried this, but perform_create is being called for superuser as well. Basically I want to apply following login with the help of permissions:
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            serializer.save()
        else:
            employee = models.Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            serializer.save(employee=employee)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Custom permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) see the following example.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsNotSuperuserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'You are super user.' # Your custom message.

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return not request.user.is_superuser
        self.message = 'you are not logged in' # your custom message
        return False



class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyClass.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.serializer_class 

        return serializers.MyUserSerializer 

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            permission_classes = [IsNotSuperuserPermission]
        else:
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        employee = models.Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        serializer.save(employee=employee)
```

in `get_permissions` you can assign one or more permission to every action.